# Kill jobs from the background

Tags: bash, jobs

I have two jobs running

```
me@me:~$ jobs
[1]-  Running                 emacs --daemon &
[2]+  Running                 emacs &
```

I want to kill the job 1 and get it done in a cumbersome way

```
fg 1
Ctrl + C
```

Is it possible to kill it on the background without put it to the forewords.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find this [link](https://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/x9644.html) helpful.

Basically, type `jobs` to see a job list, and type `kill %{job #}` to kill a specific one.

So in your example, `kill %1` should do the trick.